# Can't get json data inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
[
  {
    "May": [
        {
          "year": 1994,
          "date": "2"
        },
        {
          "Sequence": 2,
          "Type": "Images"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "1122"
  }
]
```

I can get id except "date" which is inside array. And date just show me `undefined`.

Comment: Show us your code which you using to find date?

Comment: arr[i].May[1]['date']

Comment: I also tried  arr[i].May[1][2] but it still not working

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
  {
    "May": [
        {
          "year": 1994,
          "date": "2"
        },
        {
          "Sequence": 2,
          "Type": "Images"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "1122"
  }
];

alert(data[0].May[0]["date"]);
```

You should use `arr[i].May[0]['date']`, `date` is inside the object of the 0th index of array May.

Answer (score 0):

Array will be start with the **index 0** only . so from your json data 0th  position only have the key named "date". So you should use **like @void answer**.
If you had doubt about whether data is have or not use like below

```
if(data[0].May[0]["date"])
   alert(data[0].May[0]["date"]);
```

Thank you :)